# Book time on replacing thermostats on 2007 Silverado HD2500 with 6.6 diesel

Tags: chevrolet, silverado, thermostat, book-hours

Overheating issues. Was looking for book time to replace thermostats is all.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact book time (don't have access to that information), but I'd be charging two hours labour for the thermostat.

You also need to factor in replacement coolant (plus disposal), etc. Plus diagnostic time; no decent mechanic will just take your word for it - "It's overheating, please change the thermostat"; they'd want to find out why it's overheating, and cure the actual problem, whatever it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the thermostat every time you replace the water pump. Usually you replace water pump every time you change your timing belt. Or if you have schedule for water pump replacement follow it.

Comment: Your answer is totally sound and right, still you fell victim to an misunderstandig: OP asked for the "Book time", that is the time the Dealership is supposed to bill the customer for a certain work. That "book time" is specified by the manufacturer

Comment: What book time on a car that is manufactured in 2007?